# How can I set a default value of a field in SQL Server to a substring of GUID?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way I can set a default value of a field in a table in a SQL Server 2012 database so that I don't need to enter it?

I realize this does not set a perfect duplicate but it's good enough for my needs.

```
guid.ToString().Substring(10);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.fooblat
(
  id INT, 
  splungemort CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT LEFT(NEWID(),10)
);

INSERT dbo.fooblat(id) VALUES(1),(2);

SELECT id,splungemort FROM dbo.fooblat;
```

Results:

```
id  splungemort
1   F2E81CC6-F  
2   7B04996B-8
```

If `LEFT()` doesn't give the ten characters you're after, you can look up `RIGHT()` or `SUBSTRING()`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, the default length of the GUID in string format is 36.

```
-- default length
select len(newid())
```

Second, the string contains for hyphens.

```
-- sample number
select newid()
```

8260C133-5123-4C61-AD6E-74BC355E3E3B

Third, I do not know why you would want to keep a hyphen in the result.  Left, right or substring (mid) can be used to grab the characters.

```
-- Grab ten characters
select left(replace(newid(), '-', ''), 10)
```

Last but not least, there is no guarantee that the result will be unique.